# Load image from url and draw to HTML5 Canvas

Tags: javascript, html, image, canvas, html5-canvas

I am having trouble loading an image from a url in javascript. The code below works, but I don't want to have to have the image loaded from html. I want to load the image from a url using pure javascript.

```
var c = document.getElementById("myCanvas");
var ctx = c.getContext("2d");
var img = document.getElementById("imImageId");
ctx.drawImage(img, 0, 0);
```

Answer (score 34, accepted):

Simple, just create an image object in JavaScript, set the `src`, and wait for the load event before drawing.

## Working Example:

```js
var c = document.getElementById("myCanvas");
var ctx = c.getContext("2d");
var img = new Image();
img.onload = function() {
    ctx.drawImage(img, 0, 0);
};
img.src = 'https://cdn.sstatic.net/stackexchange/img/logos/so/so-icon.png';
```

```html
<canvas id="myCanvas"></canvas>
```

Comment: Prefer `img.addEventListener("load", () => ctx.drawImage(img, 0, 0))` over setting `onload`.

Comment: @SebastianSimon Can you explain why?

Comment: It can be more-flexible for elements in the DOM, but if it's not in the DOM (as is the case here) `onload` is fine.

Comment: @holydragon _In general_, [`addEventListener`](//developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener) is preferable over the `on*` properties. A possible advantage here is that you don’t have to worry about accidentally overwriting a previous `load` event handler. The `on*` properties come from the legacy DOM 0 event model; they are still being added for newer event types, and they can be used for feature detection. However, for regular event binding, `addEventListener` is where the standardization efforts are currently headed. It’s in a way “more standard”.

Answer (score 7):

**Easy as this...**

```
var img=new Image();
img.onload=start;
img.src="myImage.png";
function start(){
    ctx.drawImage(img,0,0);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

In case you want a `Promise` version instead of the `onload` approach:

```js
async function drawImage(url, ctx) {
  let img = new Image();
  await new Promise(r => img.onload=r, img.src=url);
  ctx.drawImage(img, 0, 0);
}

let ctx = document.querySelector("#myCanvas").getContext("2d");
await drawImage("https://example.com/image.png", ctx);
```