# Load two images in a single img tag one after another

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, image

I want to load two images in a single `<img />` tag. First small image will be shown by `src` attribute and second large image will be inside `data-src` attribute but one image will be shown at once, that will be in `src` attribute. I want when page load small image will be load and show first and after completing loading of large image in the background it will be replaced by small image so that we can see large image. I have the code that will take large image from `data-src` attribute and place large image in `src` attribute.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#image4").load(function(){
        var imgDefer = document.getElementsByTagName('img');
        for (var i=0; i<imgDefer.length; i++) {
            if(imgDefer[i].getAttribute('data-src')) {
                imgDefer[i].setAttribute('src',imgDefer[i].getAttribute('data-src'));
            } }
    });
});
```

I want to do this because I don't want to wait for long time to load large image, instead I want to see the small image first. I am facing the problem when page load, it's loading small and large images in parallel. For your information images have the drag and zoom functionality.
Current live code is here: http://virtualepark.com/new1/demo.html

Comment: You can't do that. Image tags are selfclosing and only take a single `src` attribute/

Comment: since the question is tagged with jquery and javascript it is possible to load the images @Paulie_D

Answer (score 1):

The code you posted here is not deployed on your server - there is some other stuff using the `mousewheel`-event.

Try loading the big image hidden in the background and once its loaded, set the url of the visible image:

```
//get all images
$('img').each(function(i, img) {
 var img = $(img);
 //if they have a data-src
 if(img.attr('data-src')) {
   //register for the load-event for the initial image
   img.one('load', function() {
     //if small image is loaded, begin loading the big image
     //create new hidden image
     var hiddenImg = new Image();
     hiddenImg.onload = function() {
          //if the hidden image is loaded, set the src-attribute of the
          //real image (it will show instantly)
          img.attr('src', img.attr('data-src'));
      };
      //trigger loading of the resource
      hiddenImg.src = img.attr('data-src');
     });
   });
});
```

(credits to [Load image from url and draw to HTML5 Canvas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29572560/load-image-from-url-and-draw-to-html5-canvas))

Comment: Thanks Johannes, But still both images start loading in a parallel way. I want large image should start loading after small has been completely loaded.

Comment: @RohitChaudhary I have extended the script to achieve this behavior, but I don't think this is the best way. The big image should be loaded as fast as possible.

Comment: @RohitChaudhary ok, please approve my answer in this case

Answer (score 0):

you can load to hidden tag and after load complet change them.

Answer (score 0):

you can try to start the loading after the image is loaded.

```
$('img').load(function(){
    var bigImgSrc = $(this).data('src');
    var img = $(this);

    if(bigImgSrc != img.prop('src')){
      var bigImg =$('<img>').prop('src', bigImgSrc);
      bigImg.load(function(){
        img.prop('src', bigImgSrc);
      });
    }
});
```

I'm not 100% sure if you need to append the `bigImg` to the DOM or if it also loads like this. If you need to add it to the DOM use `bigImg.hide().appendTo('body')` and then use the remove funtion when loaded.

You should also be aware that the load-function not work in all cases, see https://api.jquery.com/load-event/

*edit* there was in an infinity loop in the prev. code example