# Make a <figure> containing multiple <img> images, appear as a single image

Tags: html, css, image, figure

I have a `<figure>` tag containing two `<img>` (let's say, a picture, and a signature positioned at the bottom). Is it possible to treat the `<figure>` tag as a single image, such that when right clicking onto the image and clicking on "View image" (inside the browser), the image shown would be a merge of the two images?

Comment: It's not possible if they are two (or more) separate images. When you right click and view image, it opens the link directly to the image asset. You'd have to merge the images into one using an image editor and serve that new merged image to your page instead.

Answer (score 0):

No, this is not possible. The `View image` command shows exactly one image. You'll have to merge the individual image files into one.

Comment: Any idea to achieve something similar without having to merge the pictures? I have tons of pictures and I'd like to give the possibility to choose weather to show the signature or not...

Comment: You can just merge them programmatically. Either with image processing software on the server or it should also be possible client-side with Javascript painting both images in a canvas. Similar to this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29572560/load-image-from-url-and-draw-to-html5-canvas

Comment: Will the auto-painting on a canvas determine a loss of quality?

Comment: I don't think so. At least it shouldn't. But I'm not familiar with the implementation.