# Parse image pixel coordinates from URL

Tags: javascript, jquery, tampermonkey

Is it possible to parse a image's pixel coordinates from a URL?

Possibly log each pixel coordinate and the hex value of that current pixel index using variables and forEach?

var pixelcoord = foo..

var hexcolorofcoord = foo.

console.log(pixelcoord) //example output = 123, 456

console.log(hexcolorofcoord ) //example output = #fff000

Comment: So somehow, for each pixel how could I log the coordinate and hex color of that pixel.

Comment: Definitely possible! Take a look at HTML canvas. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29572590/2535504) and [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Canvas_API) for starts. Maybe someone will have the brain power to write up a more comprehensive answer at this hour. Good luck!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved using MarvinJ.

```
image = new MarvinImage();
image.load("https://i.imgur.com/2sGyojB.png", imageLoaded);

function imageLoaded() {

for (var y = 0; y < image.getHeight(); y++) {
    for (var x = 0; x < image.getWidth(); x++) {
        var red = image.getIntComponent0(x, y);
        var green = image.getIntComponent1(x, y);
        var blue = image.getIntComponent2(x, y);
        var alpha = image.getAlphaComponent(x, y);
        var RBGCOLOR = "rgb(" + red + "," + green + "," + blue + ")";

        var HexColor = red.toString(16) + green.toString(16) + blue.toString(16)

        if (HexColor === "ffffff") {
            console.log("White") // If it's a white pixel, log
        } else {
            console.log(HexColor) // Log the hex color.
            console.log(x + " : " + y) // Log the X & Y coordinates for each pixel.
        }

    }
}
}
```